# Emacs Elisp dynamic interactive prompt

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to have a dynamic prompt from my elisp function.  I want something like replace-regexp where it will show you the last regexp entered.  I tried
  (interactive 
   (concat "sab" "bab")))
 that doesnt work!

I also tried message like format 
(interactive "s %s" last-used-regexp)

and that doesn't work!
Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`M-x find-function` is your friend. It will tell you how anything in emacs works by showing you the source code. Using it, I find that `query-regexp-replace` calls `query-replace-read-args` which calls `query-replace-read-from` which calls `read-from-minibuffer` using a prompt created from the last used regexp, which is saved in the dotted pair `query-replace-defaults`.

So:

```
(defun my-func ()
  "Do stuff..."
  (interactive)
  (read-from-minibuffer "Regexp? " (first query-replace-defaults)))
```

is a command that throws up a prompt with the last entered regexp as the default.

Answer (score 10):

Use a variable for input history, and interactive with a list:

```
(defvar my-func-history nil)

(defun my-func (str)
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "Input string: " (car my-func-history) nil nil 'my-func-history)))
  (insert str))
```

If you don't want the last value entered in there initially, change the `(car my-func-history)` to `nil`.  You can of course up/down arrow to go through the history at the prompt.